# Is there draw.io api to manipulate diagrams?

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

I want to create importer/exporter for draw.io. But I can't find how to work with drawio format programmatically. Is there any API available for the purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Nasdanika Drawio API](https://docs.nasdanika.org/core/drawio/index.html) to read, manipulate and save Drawio diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

draw.io is based on mxGraph so probably you will have to use mxGraph's API.
If you want programmatically manipulate the draw.io diagrams file with java you can take a look at this my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381781/how-to-read-write-compressed-mxgraph-diagram-with-java/70393846#70393846)

Hoping this is helpful for you