How to integrate console application with draw.io application by giving mermaid script as input and flow diagram should be in draw.io as output
Title: How to integrate a console application with Draw.io to generate flow diagrams from Mermaid scripts?
Body:
I'm attempting to integrate a console application with Draw.io to automate the generation of flow diagrams from Mermaid scripts. The desired workflow involves providing a Mermaid script as input to the console application and obtaining a flow diagram as output in Draw.io format.
I've extensively searched for documentation or resources on achieving this integration, but haven't found any direct solutions. It appears that Draw.io doesn't offer a public API for external applications to create or manipulate diagrams programmatically, especially from desktop applications like a C# console application.
Despite the lack of a direct API, I'm still keen on exploring possible workarounds or alternative approaches to accomplish this task. If anyone has insights, suggestions, or prior experience with similar integrations, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Hi there! Can you describe your problem more generally? It sounds like you want to draw a flowchart. Why do you need draw.io? Can you use https://godiagram.com/winforms/latest/index.html ? Or does this address your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543817/is-there-draw-io-api-to-manipulate-diagrams
